# Define variable in gradle application, read it in java

Tags: java, gradle

Hello I need to enter directory in gradle and I would like to send it as string to java file:

```
project(':MyGenerator') {
    apply plugin: 'application'

    mainClassName = "com.test.MyGenerator"
    outputDir = "../Example/src/main/java-gen"

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }

    task createDocs {
        def docs = file(outputDir)
        docs.mkdirs()
    }
}
```

And I would like to send outputDir variable to my java class:

```
public class MyGenerator {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        (...)
        new Generator().generateAll(schema, "../Example/src/main/java-gen");
    }
```

}

So I don't need to hardcode destination path in generateAll method. I want to make it dependant from only 1 variable in code which would be set in gradle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added in gradle:

```
run {
    args outputDir
}
```

Passed my variable as argument and in java code:

```
public class MyGenerator {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        (...)
        new Generator().generateAll(schema, args[0]);
    }
}
```

Switched hardcoded path to args[0].